# What is the complexity of given problem?

Tags: computational-complexity

I have found the solution to be nLogn but i dont know if i am correct!

```
for i in range(n):
     for j in range(log(i)):
         #some operation O(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its **O(log(n!))**.Which can also be written as O(log(n^n)) or O(n*log(n)) 
As you can see the number of operations will be *log(1)+log(2)+...log(n)=log(n!)*

**MORE EXPLANATION**
-when i=1, j will run upto log(i)=log(1)
-similarly when i=2,j will run upto log(i)=log(2)
Thats why total operations are *log(1)+log(2)+...log(n)=log(n!)*

Comment: could you please explain?

Comment: $log(n!)$ is not equivalent to $log(n^2)$

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, your algorithm has complexity
$$ log(1)+log(2)+...+log(n) = log(n!) $$
and by [Stirling Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) you have
$$ log(n!) = O(n\cdot log(n))$$